# Como pegar os resultados de duas tabelas consultando um com PDO?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Tenho a tabela estabelecimento, tabela unidade e tabela profissional.
Na tabela unidade, eu tenho o idestabelecimento.
Na tabela profissional, eu tenho o idunidade.
Preciso buscar todos os dados dos profissionais pelo id do estabelecimento.
Outra coisa, o estabelecimento tem N unidades e cada unidade tem N profissionais.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

PHP:

```
<?php
$idestabel = $_GET['idestabel'];

$getUnits=$pdo->prepare("SELECT idunidade, unidade FROM unidade WHERE idestabelecimento=:idestabel");
$getUnits->bindValue(":idestabel", $idestabel);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece ser apenas uma questão de realizar uma consulta com Inner Join em um relacionamento muitos para 1, segue um exemplo para cada situação (muitos para 1, 1 para muitos e muitos para muitos):

*// para relacionamento 1 para muitos ou muitos para 1*

```
SELECT * FROM TabelaPai
INNER JOIN TabelaFilha ON TabelaPai.Id = TabelaFilha.IdTabelaPai
WHERE TabelaFilha.IdDeAlgumaCoisa = AlgumId
```

*// para relacionamentos muitos para muitos*

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tabela1
INNER JOIN (
    Tabela2 INNER JOIN TabelaLigacao ON Tabela2.Id = TabelaLigacao.IdTabela2
) ON Tabela1.Id = TabelaLigacao.IdTabela1
WHERE Tabela2.IdDeAlgumaCoisa = AlgumId
```

Trate a tabela de unidade de como pai de profissionais, sendo um relacionamento de *1 unidade para muitos profissionais* (de acordo com a estrutura apresentada), aplicando o exemplo de *1 para muitos* ou *muitos para 1*, você obterá o resultado esperado.

Comment: Tentei a sua 1a. sugestão e deu certo.
Valeu.